# load csv file of gzip file into hive

Tags: amazon-s3, hive

I had a file which is the format of gzip consisting of csv file;I want to load the data into hive ? how can i do ?I create table with textfile and load in ,but cannot work ,Also set coedc ,buit also not work

Comment: What is the file name?

Comment: xxxxx.gz~  do ypu have some solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your file ends with `.gz`

---

#### Demo

(Done on a local file system)

**bash**

```
bash$ cat | gzip - >mytable/mydata.gz~
1
2
3
```

**hive**

```
create external table mytable (i int);
```

---

```
select * from mytable;
```

---

```
+--------+
|   i    |
+--------+
| (null) |
+--------+
```

**bash**

```
bash$ mv mytable/mydata.gz~ mytable/mydata.gz
```

**hive**

```
select * from mytable;
```

---

```
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
+---+
```