# Hive : select * no result

Tags: hive

I have an **EXTERNAL** hive table store in **LZO** format. There are some lines in this table, but I can't get the data by "**select ***". There must be some problems with my table format, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tableName(
    column1 string
)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
    column2 string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
    'com.hadoop.mapred.DeprecatedLzoTextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
    'hdfs://.../tableName'

select count(*) from tableName; //return 1
select * from tableName; //return nothing
select column1, column2 from tableName group by column1,column2; //return data1 data2
select * from tableName where column2='data2'; //return nothing
```

Only "select * " return nothing. Maybe "select * " is not executed through map-reduce?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [load csv file of gzip file into hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450451/load-csv-file-of-gzip-file-into-hive)

Answer (score 0):

I find that the simple SQL (without count, sum, group by and so on) will not be executed by map-reduce, that will go through fetch job (directly read hdfs file). However, My hdfs file is stored in lzo format, there will be some problem to read it.

The one solution is forcing simple SQL go to map-reduce.

```
set hive.fetch.task.conversion=none;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry for the real reason.
I forgot the parameters for LZO, thus the hdfs file is TEXTFILE format :(

```
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec;
```